# Calling Listbox in Python 3 got an attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make a list in my game, so i called `Listbox` which i have already imported tkinter.
and when i run the code, the console threw that `NameError: name 'ListBox' is not defined`

So i tried `import tkinter as gui`,
`ls = gui.Tk()` and `lsbox = gui.Listbox(ls)`

and what i have got is `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ListBox'`

So how can I fix that error?

```py
from tkinter import *  
import tkinter as gui
from random import randint

#code open the first window

print("Listbox setup...", end="")
ls = Tk()
lsbox = ListBox(ls, bg="yellow", fg="orange", selectbackground="grey")
lsbox.pack()
print("OK!")
```

console:

```py
= RESTART: /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Testing TECH/python/hit-and-blow.py =
~~~===hit and blow===~~~
*important: install tkinter on your PC to make this work.*
mainwin setup...OK!
Listbox setup...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Testing TECH/python/hit-and-blow.py", line 16, in <module>
    lsbox = gui.ListBox(ls, bg="yellow", fg="orange", selectbackground="grey")
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ListBox'
>>>
```

Comment: By the way when it shows the error it also show 2 windows, one is the first window that works normally(but i didn't ask it to show up), and another window titled "tk #3". So what is the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Listbox`, not `ListBox`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lbox = tk.Listbox(root, bg="yellow", fg="orange", selectbackground="grey")
lbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```